# install latest tor on xp

Tags: windows, tor-install

On my xp SP3 machine I wish to install the latest TOR update.  I am not interested in Windows upgrade.  Only TOR upgrade.  Since I cannot use the installer package, how can I continue to upgrade manually?

Comment: Tor on Windows.  And XP at that!?  LOL.  What's the point of chrome plating on a rusted hulk?   Just install some flavor of linux, huh?  It'll run much faster and you'll be so much happier.  Ubuntu isn't the greatest, but it's easy, and they have a couple of lightweight flavors for old machines (Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu Mate).

Answer (score 1):

You can attempt to install the 32-bit version of Tor Browser. If this fails, then there is no other native option with Windows XP.

https://www.torproject.org/download/languages/

Answer (score 0):

windows xp is absolutely EOL and highly insecure!!! - current firefox/torbrowser won't work on this outdated system anymore.
not to mention that using outdated firefox/torbrowser is a bad idea and must also be considered insecure! - you probably would be even more secure (perhaps except in the view of anonymity and privacy) by using a current "normal" browser.

i also wouldn't advise you to upgrade windows, since current windows tracks you by default and it is much work resp. impossible to really fix this.

i highly recommend to use a FOSS-OS to run Tor on. probably [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/) may also be interesting for you.