# Why does Tor always use the same entry point 95.154.221.3

Tags: exit-relays

My first IP (entry point) is always 95.154.221.3. Should that not change at some point. I realize it will not change with each identity change, but should it not change after a certain period of time?

I am using Win XP Pro SP3 with Tor ver. 7.5.6 (based on Mozilla Firefox 52.9.0) (32 bit)

Comment: The guard selection algorithm changes every once in a while so I’m not sure what it specifically is now, but you can generally expect it to use the same guard relay for a couple months. How long have you had that guard for?

Comment: please really read an follow this: https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/17917/5234

Answer (score 1):

It is intended behavior that the entry guard remains the same over a certain amount of time (2-3 months). This is also stated in TBB (current version 8.0.8) below the button to get a new circuit:

[image]

They also provide a link with a description and the reason. Here's part of it:

> That is normal Tor behavior. The first relay in your circuit is called an "entry guard" or "guard". It is a fast and stable relay that remains the first one in your circuit for 2-3 months in order to protect against a known anonymity-breaking attack. The rest of your circuit changes with every new website you visit, and all together these relays provide the full privacy protections of Tor.

Final remark: You should update to the current Tor browser version and ditch Win XP.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find that info re: "entry guard" anywhere in my version of 7.5.6.  Believe me, I looked.

Long story short, I installed an older version, Tor 5, into another directory.  I found it had a different entry point than my 7.6 version.

I then installed two more 7.6 Tors into directories of their own. Each worked and had different entry points. I now have four versions of Tor, each with a different "entry guard" point. In other words, I now have a choice of four separate entry points depending which copy of Tor I choose to use.

I'm not giving up on XP because I have many utilities and programs that do not work on Windows 7.  As far as ever "upgrading" to Win 10, I'll go Mac first.