# I need an older version of Tor that will work with Win XP

Tags: windows, help, tor-install

I need an older version of TOR in order to make it work on my computer. I have had the same computer for 11 years. and it is still in great condition and is still fast. But, I tried installing from your site and it just will not accept any of the versions offered. I had a working version but somebody was "Helping me" and now I can't get it to even start. Can someone please help me find what I need?
Thank you.

Comment: try archive.torproject.org

Comment: Doing a DuckDuckGo search for "Tor for XP" will give you many sites.

Comment: duplicate: https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/17917/5234