# Giving error while installing TOR on window 7

Tags: tor-install

[image]

Giving error while installing TOR on window 7. ref screenshot. i formatted my latpot and installed new window.before it is working in same window which i installed again

Comment: btw: support for windows 7 ends on 14. January 2020 (in one month), after that it must be considered as a security risk! - so in your case i would have installed an other OS. it seems similar like [this question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/17906/5234) to me... if you are low on resources (which i guess because of using 32-bit), i also suggest a current FOSS-OS because there are a bunch which use so much less resources than windows.

Comment: yeah i m looking for window 10 now. Thanks for information

Answer (score 0):

Download the 32-bit version. Here is the [link](https://www.torproject.org/download/languages/).